# Help with weird issue with modded minecraft server (closing without crashing)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-java-edition-server

My custom server (forge modded) which i have just spent all day figuring out ID conflicts with, now has just started closing on me mid load without crashing or generating a helpful log file. from the little bit of log that I do get, it appears that it crashes right in the middle of generating a line in the log file.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Whatever you did between now and 3 hours ago, undo it. That might help.

Comment: Could you give us a list of the mods you installed? if possible, in the order you installed it.

Comment: the only thing that I did was change item IDs

Comment: I also realized that I had added the alternative terrain gen mod, but when I removed it, it did not help. I will work on getting a list of mods

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's for modded minecraft tech support and we can only help with vanilla minecraft crashes.

Comment: @Virusbomb do you have a reference for that? Why vote to close a question that is at zero points and is 5 years old

Comment: @sww1235 it has recently been flagged and I came across this in the review close queue. A few users have been going through old Minecraft questions and closing/flagging them due to [this meta post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13467/modded-minecraft-server-tech-support).

Comment: @Virusbomb thanks for the meta link

Comment: No, actually in this case it was I who flagged the question, not because of the new meta post on minecraft servers but because I feel that off-topic questions should be closed as off-topic regardless of their age (in fact, my actions prompted that meta post, after I assumed without asking that the rule against modded minecraft also applied to servers)

Comment: @pppery You are correct, it should apply to both. I support closing old off-topic questions. Just because they're old doesn't mean they're above the law. (We leave that to congressmen) :)

Answer (score 2):

If it is minecraft forge 1.7.10 there is a bug for all versions of it when you download it onto your client, same with downloading it onto a server. With the client either minecraft doesn't load and shows a black screen or shows a small square of the game in the corner of the game screen. In the server it just closes, you might have to downgrade your forge with your minecraft and your server or remove all mods install them 1 by one and after installing each one open minecraft to see if it works, because it might be a conflicting mod. Or your computer does not have enough RAM to support a Forge server.

Comment: it is a 1.6.4 server

Answer (score 0):

Forge 1.7.10 had some crippling bugs that appeared out of nowhere. It causes various odd startup issues on the server side or a broken GUI on the client side. To my knowledge, most of these bugs have already been fixed. I would suggest you to update to the latest version of Minecraft Forge. If all fails, provide a Modlist with their versions for us to understand the situation more.

As to address your issue with having the log file being incomplete, try the following. Assuming you are running it on windows, In the .bat file you use for startup, add a `PAUSE` on the next line for the console to not autoclose. You may then assess the last few lines before the server gets terminated.

Comment: do you know how to do that on mac/linux

Comment: @sww1235 Assuming you are referring to how to pause it on linux/mac, then a crude way to pause it is to use `sleep`. Simply add `sleep 999` to the end of the script replacing 999 with whatever duration in seconeds you want it to wait for.

Comment: Great. that will be awesome to know. on a side note, I noticed that it **was** creating logs after I posted here. It was just not updating forge log0 but creating other weird logs. It was a block id issue with extra cells, but instead of crashing, it was just exiting. Very weird. Thanks for the help. Now I just have to fix all the item id conflicts which should be very fun.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I ran into when I first installed was that I needed to accept the EULA.

Go to the eula.txt file, change the value to true and restart the server.